# The verb "to know" followed by a bare infinitive

Tags: bare-infinitives

Some grammars say that KNOW should be followed by a bare infinitive.

**I never knew a fellow work so indefatigably.**

However, some natives say that it should be

**I never knew a fellow to work so indefatigably.**

Any advice? Any rule on the issue?

Comment: You will find numerous websites that offer guidance on this question, as in: https://www.learn-english-today.com/lessons/lesson_contents/verbs/bare-infinitives.html

Comment: Have you checked the website? It has nothing to offer on the matter.

Comment: I won't use the first sentence.  Second is fine. The verb 'know' is different from verbs like make one do, help one finish, let them go, see them go/going etc.

Comment: This sentence (1) was written by a native speaker.